# ExtendScript (After Effects Script) How to add opacity keyframe to any selected layer at current time?

Tags: extendscript

This is what I tried, but not working :/

```
var myLayer = app.project.item(index).layer(index).propertySpec;
var myProperty = myLayer.opacity;
myProperty.setValue(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a keyframe you have to set the Property to a value at a particular time using `setValueAtTime`, thus:

```
myProperty.setValueAtTime(newValue, time)
```

You can also change the value at an existing key thus:

```
myProperty.setValueAtKey(keyIndex, newValue)
```

If you don't know what the property is going to be, you can check that it is keyframe-able by testing

```
if(myProperty.canVaryOverTime === true){ doTheThings() }
```

I feel like the most helpful thing I can do right now is point you to the [docs for the Property object](https://docs.aenhancers.com/properties/property/#property-setvalueattime), they should give you a leg-up.